# MeteorJS Publication and Subscription

Tags: meteor

Subscribing to all data can take a large amount of time and stressful in the server specially if you got thousands of data; however there are time that we can not avoid it.

For example:

I got a dashboard where in I need to have all the user data available for look up.

I can not put limits to it on the publish since I won't be able to search the user collection properly.

Is there a way you can recommend (a package or a process) that is capable of subscribing large amount of data in a faster way and less stressful in the server? Thank you

Comment: Do you require it to be reactive? If the answer is no, then you can use meteor methods. I had similar problem publishing thousands of records last time. Literally the page took about so much time (>30-60 seconds) to publish all the records. So I used methods instead, and it worked for my use case.

Comment: @Kishor - Thank you for your response, can you tell me the process please on how did you do it? Thank you. A short sample code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not an answer to your original question** but I am adding the process to use meteor methods instead of publications (no reactivity).

For the following example, lets say the collection with large number of records is "UserPosts"

```js
//on server side
Meteor.methods({
    getUserPosts: function (userId) {
       return UserPosts.find({ userId: userId });
    }
});

//on client side
Template.yourTemplate.onCreated(function () {
    Session.set("current-user-posts", []);
    var template = this;
    template.autorun(function () {
        var userId = Meteor.userId(); //Instead of this, add your reactive data source. That is, this autorun will run whenever Meteor.userId() changes, so change it according to your needs.
        Meteor.call("getUserPosts", function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log("There is an error while getting user posts..");
            result = err ? [] : result;
            Session.set("current-user-posts", result);
        });
    });
});

Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    userPosts: function () {
        return Session.get("current-user-posts");
    }
});

Template.yourTemplate.onDestroyed(function () {
    Session.set("current-user-posts", null);
});
```

Now you can use `Session.get("current-user-posts")` in your template helpers and other places to get user posts.

Comment: thank you so much . . let me try to test it out, maybe it will sort out my issue :)

Comment: It worked; however, I am puzzled on how to display the data on the client. It seems the helper is useless unless if there is a way to pass the data from the Template onCreated to the Template helper.

May I know how did you present the data on the client?

Comment: I think that is what the session is for correct?

Comment: It is working, but works like PHP . . you have to refresh before you can see the changes :) but I think this will work for now in loading large amount of data.